# Create a fork on a sklearn transformer pipeline to allow data to pass through

Tags: scikit-learn

I have an sklearn pipeline that looks like this

[image]

You'll notice the duplicate step, `features_to_vectorize`, in the left and right side of the `FeatureUnion`. `features_to_vectorize` is the result of applying a `DictVectorizer` to a pandas DataFrame column. I'd like to then take `features_to_vectorize` and concatenate it with a transformation on itself. My current setup duplicates the transformation because I'm not sure how to create a fork at `features_to_vectorize` where I can create a passthrough for that data but also apply a transformation on that data and later `FeatureUnion` it. Any ideas how to better set this up to avoid duplicate computation? Thanks

```
sum_along_columns = FunctionTransformer(np.sum, kw_args={"axis": 1})
col_trans = ColumnTransformer([("features_to_vectorize", DictVectorizer(), "col")])
out = FeatureUnion(
    [
        ("pipeline", Pipeline([("d_vec", col_trans), ("sum", sum_along_columns)])),
        ("column_transformer", col_trans),
    ]
)
```

Ideally it should look like

[image]

**SOLUTION**:

```
col_trans = ColumnTransformer([("features_to_vectorize", DictVectorizer(), "col")])
ident = FunctionTransformer()

fts = FeatureUnion([("sum", SumColumns()), ("ident", ident)])
out = Pipeline([("dv", col_trans), ("sum_and_pass", fts)])
```

where `SumColumns` is a simple transformation `np.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1,1)` in order to conform to 2d outputs that sklearn enforces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ColumnTransformer` can send the same column to multiple transformers, so this should do:

```py
sum_along_columns = FunctionTransformer(np.sum, kw_args={"axis": 1})
col_trans = ColumnTransformer([("features_to_vectorize", DictVectorizer(), "col")])

split = ColumnTransformer([
    ('sum', sum_along_columns, [0]),
    ('ident', 'passthrough', [0]),
])

out = Pipeline([
    ('vectorize', col_trans),
    ('split', split),
])
```

One issue is that after the 'vectorize' step in the pipeline you have an array not a frame, so we can't rely on the feature name in `split`, and hence `[0]`.

You could also stick to `FeatureUnion` and implement your own simple identity transformer, e.g. using `FunctionTransformer` again, instead of using the `ColumnTransformer`'s `'passthrough'`.

Comment: That makes sense but only works if the output of `DictVectorizer` has 1 column. I'd like to sum along all columns of its output and passthrough all columns as well. I ended up using your suggestion of creating an identify function for Feature Union instead and that worked well!

Comment: Ah, right, I shouldn't have used just `[0]`, you'll want all of the newly vectorized columns.  That should be doable, maybe using a slice or callable?  Anyway, I'm glad the second approach is working.